# Solutions for a slanted roof

Tags: structural-engineering, fasteners, wood

[image]

I'm using I-Joists to span this 27' vaulted living room and create a shed style roof. I've got two problems. Because of the angle, the joist won't make full contact with the walls (short of 20 years worth of settling), and of course it's got a tendency to want to slide. My ideas were to cut angles in the top plates of the walls so that the full surface area bears the load, and to fasten brackets from wall to joist on the outside of both walls to prevent the slide. Do these seem like reasonable solutions? Any better solutions?

Comment: Cut notches so the joists sit with flat faces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. As Solar Mike pointed out, Attach a notched block, or wedge block to the bottom chord of the joist.
2. Add a diagonal bracket at the inner side of the stud-joist connection.

You really need to do is keep the frames from deformation due to lateral load.

[image]

Comment: Why do you recommend the bracket to go inside instead of outside? The reason I thought outside was that this way I could fasten to the non-load bearing part of the bottom chord, keeping the important part free of holes.

Comment: Think about the lateral displacement of a rectangle box, where is the most effective place to prevent the deformation? If this is a DIY job, you shall consider posting this question on the DIY forum.

Answer (score 2):

Many fastener companies have a fastener made for this specific application. They test these fasteners under all kinds of situations, winds, earthquakes, extra loads.

Here is one made by Simpson Fasteners at a cost of about $7.59.

.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a million, I had no idea about these. I'm definitely going to use them!

Comment: @JaredCravens, sure, please check the answer as an accepted answer, so others can use it too.